# Tem como mudar esse código JS para abrir o link em outra aba ao ser clicado

Tags: javascript, html

Eu manjo nada de códigos. Se alguém puder me ajudar. Esse abaixo é o código JS... ele abre na mesma aba o vídeo... se tiver como mudar o código para abrir em um *popup* ou em nova aba, eu agradeceria.

```
$(function() {

  var videohtml5 = $('.videoGallery .videohtml5');
  var liHeight = $('.videoGallery li').height();

  // BLOGGER
  videohtml5.click(function() {
    var videoID = $(this).attr('data-videoID');
    var videos = $('<div class="meuVideo"><center> <video width="100%" controls="controls" autoplay="true" poster="https://i.imgur.com/SoclbRY.png" src="https://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=' + videoID + '" type="video/mp4"></video></center> </div>');

    $('.meuVideo, .nowPlaying').remove();
    $(this).parents().eq(2).append(videos);

  });

  // Fechar Videos
  $('.close').click(function() {
    $('.meuVideo, .nowPlaying').remove();
  });

})
```

Comment: Só dá pra fazer isso se o usuário clicar em alguma coisa (ex., um botão "abrir vídeo"), caso contrário o navegador bloqueia a popup.

Comment: amigo. esse e link de teste olhe como ele abre.. clique em algum episodio para vc ver http://programarpostagem.blogspot.com.br/2017/10/strange-todos-os-episodios-formato.html

Comment: sim.. mas tem como mudar o codigo acima. para tipo abrir em outra janela ou ate mesmo em popup

Comment: Esse link pede explicitamente para desligar o ad block, e só por isso é que funciona, caso contrário seria certamente bloqueado

Comment: amigo vc estar errado... desabilitei o gadget. olhe la novamente e faca o teste ele roda com ad block ligado

Comment: testei aqui e ele roda com adblock

Comment: Ainda há pouco testei e o vi o aviso do adblock, mas agora de facto não vejo. Ainda assim não abre numa nova aba a menos que eu desligue explicitamente o adblock (como fiz agora para testar)

Comment: amigo. acho que vc entendeu errado.. ao clicar no episodio ele abre na mesma aba... eu queria saber se tem como ele abrir em outra aba ao ser clicado..   e tipo quando clicar ele abrir em outra..

Comment: e tipo esse codigo ..

Comment: <div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">
<a href="https://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=%203906ae6d9485568c" target="_blank">click aqui</a></div>

Comment: so que não sei se e possivel fazer isso no arquivo js..  não manjo nada de html.. na verdade nao sei nada de programação

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você consegue com a função `window.open()` e depois inserindo o HTML com `document.write`. Veja que alterei a variável `videos` tirando os *parênteses* e o *$*:

```
$(function() {

  var videohtml5 = $('.videoGallery .videohtml5');
  var liHeight = $('.videoGallery li').height();

  // BLOGGER
  videohtml5.click(function() {
    var videoID = $(this).attr('data-videoID');
    var videos = '<div class="meuVideo"><center> <video width="100%" controls="controls" autoplay="true" poster="https://i.imgur.com/SoclbRY.png" src="https://www.blogger.com/video-play.mp4?contentId=' + videoID + '" type="video/mp4"></video></center> </div>';

    // Abro uma janela popup
    video_popup = window.open("pagina_da_popup.html","video_popup","width=400, height=200");

    $('.meuVideo, .nowPlaying').remove();

    // Insiro os dados na popup
    video_popup.document.write(videos);

  });

  // Fechar Videos
  $('.close').click(function() {
    $('.meuVideo, .nowPlaying').remove();
  });

})
```

> **Obs.:** Onde tem *pagina_da_popup.html*, não precisa necessariamente ser uma página existente no servidor. Mesmo que você não coloque nada
>   na URL (assim: `video_popup = window.open("","video_popup","width=400,
>   height=200");`) irá funcionar, porque a popup é apenas uma janela do
>   navegador, e não precisa necessariamente ter uma URL. Apenas irá aparecer, antes do `document.write` entrar em ação, a mensagem *HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found*.

Comment: amigo era isso mesmo.. mas tem so um pequeno problema. o video abre mas fica maior que a tela. tipo tem como enquadra ele na tela depois que expandila. clique e veja em algum episodio o video abre em popup. mas ele fica maior que a tela  https://programarpostagem.blogspot.com.br/2017/10/strange-todos-os-episodios-formato.html

Comment: amigo obrigado pela sua ajuda e tempo dedicado ao meu problema..   constatei aqui que o error nao e no codigo. e nem no template de ambos os sites.. pq mudei o template de ambos e o error so continua no meu site original.. deve ser alguma configuracao. nele... vou olhar aqui oque tem de errado. obrigado mas uma vez...